# How do I run two commands with pipenv scripts using &&?

Tags: pipenv

This is fairly easy to do with cargo and npm.

When I run it from the shell `$ pylint src && pylint tests`, I have no problems.

But when I run it as a pipenv script

```
[scripts]
lint = "pylint  src  && pylint tests"
```

```sh
$ pipenv run lint
************* Module &&
&&:1:0: F0001: No module named && (fatal)
```

Pylint thinks `&&` is another module.
Is the pipenv runtime not just the terminal?

Comment: does `lint = "pylint  src; pylint tests"` work?

Comment: @JohnD `No module named src; `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed on [this issue](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2038) of their GitHub tracker, this is caused by the fact that:

> this is to difficult to get right, especially since Pipenv needs to support a cross-platform experience

<sup>*Source: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2038#issuecomment-387506323*</sup>

There is a work around pointed in the issue report itself that could be a good fit for you:

```
[scripts]
lint = "bash -c 'pylint src && pylint tests'"
```

`pipenv` relevant issues on their tracker:

- https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2878 — the answer of the maintainer here says more about the portability issue implementing this would cause
- https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2283 — is interesting because it offers another solution, which is to use [PyInvoke](http://www.pyinvoke.org/)
- https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2160
- https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2038